# PHP odbc ON DUPLICATE KEY

Tags: php, odbc

i need another pair of eyes to see where did i go wrong. Running the codes below gives me this error.

```
Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\ClinicalSolution\UpdateStatusControl.php on line 82
Testing of queue status failed. Error in SQL.
```

This is my codes. Without the "ON DUPLICATE KEY", my insert statement runs smoothly so im not really sure where did i go wrong.

```
$TestQueueStatus = "INSERT INTO QueueLine (NRIC,QueueTime,ActiveStatus,PriorityStatus)
        VALUES ('".$_SESSION['NRICnumber']."','".$QueueTime."','1','".$PriorityStatus."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  PriorityStatus='".$PriorityStatus."'";

$TestQueueLine=odbc_exec($dbc,$TestQueueStatus);
    if (!$TestQueueLine) {
          exit("Testing of queue status  failed. Error in SQL.");
    }
odbc_close($dbc);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add a semicolon at the end of your SQL query?

```
$TestQueueStatus = "INSERT INTO QueueLine (NRIC,QueueTime,ActiveStatus,PriorityStatus)
                    VALUES ('".$_SESSION['NRICnumber']."','".$QueueTime."','1','".$PriorityStatus."') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE  PriorityStatus='".$PriorityStatus."';";
```